# What's wrong with my .html() syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

When I type out the following code:

> $('.whatever').html("LOL");

It works. But in the website I'm building I need to add more than just a string.

This is what I wish to add:

```
<div class="pic"><img class="left" src="img/happy-man.jpg"/ ></div>
<div class="pic"><img class="happy" src="img/happy-woman.jpg"/ ></div>
<div class="pic"><img class="right" src="img/happy-celeb.jpg"/ ></div>
```

But nothing happens when I put the HTML code above into the html() function. I'm wondering what obvious mistake I'm doing in regards to the syntax. Appreciate it!

Comment: Probably need to escape quotes. Show us what exactly you entered

Comment: Are you escaping the quotes? Those would break the .html function if you were doing .html("<div class=" <---- goes bang here

Comment: Please paste few more lines, showing how you have stored the above HTML string and how you are invoking the .html() function.

Comment: Multiline string isn't that easier in javascript. Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/how-to-create-multiline-strings to understand how to make it work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.whatever').html('<div class="pic"><img class="left" src="img/happy-man.jpg"/ ></div><div class="pic"><img class="happy" src="img/happy-woman.jpg"/ ></div><div class="pic"><img class="right" src="img/happy-celeb.jpg"/ ></div>')
```

The following code will allow you to replace the html contents of the div

or you just make a string

```
text= '<div class="pic"><img class="left" src="img/happy-man.jpg"/ ></div>'+'<div class="pic"><img class="happy" src="img/happy-woman.jpg"/ ></div>'
$('.whatever').html(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with single quotes `$('.whatever').html('LOL');`

http://jsfiddle.net/83DSu/1/

Answer (score 0):

It can work perfectly if you escape correctly

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EQtAW/2/) with three different options

```
var html1 ="<div class=\"pic\"><img class=\"left\" src=\"img/happy-man.jpg\"/ >" + 
           "</div><div class=\"pic\"><img class=\"happy\" src=\"img/happy-woman.jpg\"/ ></div>" +
           "<div class=\"pic\"><img class=\"right\" src=\"img/happy-celeb.jpg\"/ ></div>";

$('#whatever').html(html1);

var html2 = "<div class='pic'><img class='left' src='img/happy-man.jpg'/ ></div>" + 
            "<div class='pic'><img class='happy' src='img/happy-woman.jpg'/ ></div>" + 
            "<div class='pic'><img class='right' src='img/happy-celeb.jpg'/ ></div>";

$('#whatever2').html(html2);

var html3 = '<div class="pic"><img class="left" src="img/happy-man.jpg"/ ></div>' +
            '<div class="pic"><img class="happy" src="img/happy-woman.jpg"/ ></div>' +
            '<div class="pic"><img class="right" src="img/happy-celeb.jpg"/ ></div>';

$('#whatever3').html(html3);
```

Answer (score 0):

there may be a problem with single and double quotes

```
$('.whatever').html(
   '<div class="pic"><img class="left" src="img/happy-man.jpg"/ ></div>'+
   '<div class="pic"><img class="happy" src="img/happy-woman.jpg"/ ></div>'+
   '<div class="pic"><img class="right" src="img/happy-celeb.jpg"/ ></div>'
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/83DSu/

Comment: It works fine. It's only that you didn't specified correct links for the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be:

```
var imgList = [
        ["img/happy-man.jpg","left"]
        ,["img/happy-woman.jpg","happy"]
        ,["img/happy-celeb.jpg","right"]
    ], cur=0,
    whatever = $('#whatever');
    whatever.html("");

$.each(imgList,function(){
    console.log(imgList[cur][1]);
    whatever
        .append( $("<div />")
                .addClass("pic")
                .html( $("<img />")
                      .addClass(imgList[cur][1])
                      .attr("src",imgList[cur][0])
                    )
              );
        cur++;
});​
```

It looks more complicated, but it gives you a bit quicker control over the HTML and puts all of your links in one place.

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/Fwwd3/